# Unity Setting WrapMode of List Of GameObject's Textures

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change the texture wrap mode of list of GameObjects.
Simple Algorithm that i can think :
--List of GameObjects
--for each GameObject , GameObject.texturewrapMode = repeat

But i cant do that please help me.

Comment: So you have a bunch of `GameObject`s and as an initialization you want to set the wrap mode to be the same, say `repeat` on all of them one by one? Could you enclose some `C#` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand the problem right. If you have a `List<GameObject>` list that consists of `GameObject`s (obviously) then you can set their `WrapMode` via code like so:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class txWrap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> myGameObjects;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake ()
    {
        /*
         * IMPORTANT: if you use those textures' wrap mode ever again,
         * ESPECIALLY during runtime, use similar method to get the components to
         * another List, with the generic type of List<Texture>. 
         * GetComponent is slow and prone to error, use it runtime as few as possible. 
         */ 
        foreach(var item in myGameObjects)
        {
            item.GetComponent<Texture>().wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Repeat;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if you are new to coding, you might want to Google the keywords `generic`, `foreach`, `enum`. If you knew those, sorry for being preachy :)